# Project version settings keep reverting back

Tags: delphi, versioning, delphi-10.1-berlin, project-settings

I have a simple project in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. In the project settings, I have at one point checked on "Pre-Release".

Now I have two things that no matter how many times I change them, I come back and it's not saved. These are:

- Pre-Release checkbox (gets re-checked again)
- Module Version's `Release` number (changes from `0` to `1`)

[image: Screenshot of project version settings]

Note in the screenshot that the "File Version" down below shows the correct version number from when I saved it, `0.2.0`. But above, the `Release` number has changed to `1`.

In fact, I removed the option to include version settings in all other build configurations. It only exists under the `Win32 - Release` build.

---

**EDIT**

It appears actually nothing is being saved! For example, I changed the "Auto increment build" option, and that did not stay either. And my entries also get lost if I so much as navigate to a different build configuration, and switch back again. The only thing that it retains is the grid on the bottom.

---

**EDIT**

Some more strange behavior - if I set the `Release` to a larger number such as `2`, it saves it. But if I set it to `0`, it resets it back to `1`. As if it doesn't want it to be `0` (although that's the default on a new project).

Comment: I can't believe anybody is still trying to use the IDE for versioning. It's the wrong tool for the job. What tooling do you use to build?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I shouldn't have to be forced to resort to third-party tools for something which is already in the IDE. Sure, it's very buggy. Sure, I'd benefit from choosing another way. But when the option is built-in, I'd like to use it.

Comment: Personally I use my own build scripts. I know that FinalBuilder is well regarded. How do you build at the moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how or why this happened, but I was able to resolve this by re-enabling the version information on the "All Configurations" level. Once I activated that, now it's remembering whatever I change in the "Release" level.

Comment: Nice catch!  Perhaps someone could chip in with a rationale for the IDE's handling of this.

Comment: I don't know the rationale, but I noticed similar behavior too, that opening the project settings defaults to one of the build targets. It makes me always look very closely when I change any project option.

Comment: It's probably not any rationale - it's probably just the result of very poor development and nobody at Emba lifting a finger to correct it. I mean, why would it default the release to 0, but then not allow me to reset it back to 0?

Comment: Notice: this won't fix the bug in Delphi XE7 :( sad

Comment: "Project Options" was always incredibly buggy!

Comment: @WeGoToMars This wasn't meant to answer your question. It's just related to the issue.